# how to write right format of query from mongodb to pandas df by pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I want to read data from mongoDB to pandas dataframe through pymongo
so I use the function below:

```
def read_mongo(db, collection, query={}, host='localhost', port=27017, username=None, password=None, no_id=True):
""" 从Mongo读取并存储到DataFrame """
#连接MongoDB
db = _connect_mongo(host=host, port=port, username=username, password=password, db=db)
#对特定的数据库和集合进行查询
cursor = db[collection].find(query)
#读取数据并构造DataFrame
df =  pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))
#删除MongoDB中主键_id
if no_id:
    del df['_id']
return df
```

however, I don't know how to write the query in pymongo. So when I wrote the code below, error occours.

```
query =  {"ans_count":{$gte:100}
read_mongo(mydb,collection,query = query, port=27017, username=None, password=None, no_id=True)
```

Error looks like this:

```
    File "<ipython-input-85-41c57b2616f6>", line 1
query =  {"ans_count":{$gte:100}}
                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems the query I wrote evoke some kinds of syntax error.But how can I adjust the query to acquire data successfully from my db?

Comment: That error is because `$gte` is not enclosed in quotes. Try: `"$gte"`.